# How to apply a RxJava operator?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have the following object structure

```
class Object1 {
  A[] item1;    //array of Object A
  B[] item2;    //array of Object B
  C[] item3;    //array of Object C
}

class C {
  int value1;
  int value2;
  String imageUrl; //null, to be updated from a api call
}
```

I get an `Observable<Object>`  making a retrofit api call. The `imageUrl` field of object `C` is `null`, which I have to update by making another retrofit api call. I would like to use RxJava to update imageUrl for each `Object` `C` in  `C[]` in `Observable<Object1>`  . How can I do that with RxJava operators ?

I want the method to return the updated `Observable<Object1>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
getObject1()
        .flatMap(obj1 -> Observable.from(obj1.item3)
                .cast(C.class)
                .flatMap(item -> getImageUrl(item.value1).doOnNext(url -> item.imageUrl = url))
                .toList()
                .map(items -> obj1))
```

For test purposes my `getImageUrl` looked like this:

```
Observable<String> getImageUrl(int id) {
    return Observable.just(String.format("id = %d", id));
}
```

It can look something like this:

```
Observable<String> getImageUrl(int id) {
    return api.getImageUrl(id).map(SomeResponse::getImageUrl);
}
```

Comment: I am not able to access item in doOnNext() , to update the url. Also obj1 which I have to update in the last map() operator. How can I access the objects in the previous operators ?

Comment: @r7v, pay attention to the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on RxJava, but how about something like:

```
observable
    .flatMap(Observable.from(object1.item3))
    .flatMap(//do request and mix object)
    .collect()
    .filter(//map the new array to he object1)
```

Comment: I want the end result to be Observable&lt;Object1&gt;  with the updated C[] with imageurls

Comment: Collect emits an observable with a `List` of C objects. In the second flatmap you make the request and mix them returning an observable of the C object mixed,

Comment: I added a filter element at the end to change the list to a single object1